# Quarkus configurable beans with autoinjecting

Tags: cdi, quarkus

is it possible to have the same class as multiple beans with different configurations. That still get auto injection? I tried following:

```
class Config1 {
  @Scope1
  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public Parser parser1() {
    return new MySpecialParser("key1");
  }
}

class Config2 {
  @Scope2
  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public Parser parser2() {
    return new MySpecialParser("key2");
  }
}

class MySpecialParser extends Parser {
  // ...
}

abstract class Parser {
  @Inject
  @Localized("en")
  Messages messages;

  Parser(String config) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Something like this. But when I inject the `parser` the `messages` are always null.

In Spring exists AutowireCapableBeanFactory for use case like that. But maybe my initial thought is just wrong and in Quarkus I should do it differently.

Has someone a clue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Quarkus. If you create an instance manually, which you do in the producer methods, no dependency injection is performed on it and you have to fully construct the instance yourself.

You may want to inject some dependencies into the producer methods, which is possible, as each producer method parameter is actually an injection point:

```java
class Config1 {
  @Scope1
  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public Parser parser1(@Localized("en") Messages messages) {
    return new MySpecialParser("key1", messages);
  }
}
```

(There are facilities in full CDI that let you do something similar, but they are not compatible with the Quarkus build-time oriented architecture and Quarkus doesn't implement them.)